# data packet automatically activated on gingerbread 2.3.6

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, data-connection, mobile-network

I just upgraded my samsung galaxy SL to gingerbread 2.3.6
After that, everytime my data packet is automatically activated all the time.
I switch off my mobile network data and lock my phone, and then switch it on again/unlock, the network data are automatically enabled.
I ve noticed, that when i un-tick/deactivate "use packet data", lock my phone with power/lock button and then unlock it, this option is ticked again (= data are enabled).

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Install [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) to check what's happening at the time of unlocking. Without logs, its hard to tell how to fix it.

Factory reset is the last option (not applicable if your firmware is broken).

If factory reset is unable to fix it or you don't want to do factory reset, install third-party apps which could turn off data by renaming APN. I'd recommend [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) for it. After installing it, add `Data Toggle` widget on homescreen & choose `APN Renaming` as data toggle method from its settings. The bug can't by-pass it, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a factory reset will solve the problem, or if your phone is rooted and you have a custom recovery, then clear the Dalvik cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue I think.  When you power off in gingerbread you get a power off popup confirmation screen. one of the other options shown will reset packet data. if you hit that by accident it will restore the packet data connection. There is an alternative way to stop 3g rather than turning packet data off but its pretty permanent for the mobile network you use.